# Selecting map key as column in dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe from cassandrasql and I have a column which is a map in dataframe
like

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- client: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I need to select some columns from df as well a particular key from a map as column in df, instead of complete map

Let say I have a map of 
key1 -> value1
key2 -> value2
....

I need to select only key1 from map in the dataframe to be a column in my new dataframe. How can I do that

Also I am using cassandrasqlcontext.sql to get the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SparkSQL (assuming you registed the dataframe as "df")

```
context.registerDataFrameAsTable(df,"df")
val newDf =context.sql("select client.key,client.value from df where client.key='some value'")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Amon. Since I am new to spark can you please tel me how to run a query on a df? I have a cassandrasqlcontext with me.

Comment: I take it as a answer. It worked. In latest spark 1.5 context.registerDataFrameAsTable(df,"df") is changed to df.registerTempTable

Comment: Its nor working. I tried using it, and it didnt worked

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Spark2 and pyspark, this worked for me:

**SparkSQL:**

```
df.registerTempTable("table_name")
spark.sql("select client.key1 from table_name")
spark.sql("select client.key1, client.key2 from table_name")
```

**using dataframes (df):**

```
df.select("client.key1").show()
df.select("client.key1", "client.key2").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in spark sql:

```
select map_filter(your_map_name, (k,v) -> k == 'desired_key) from spark_table
```

This will give you the entire key:value as output. If you want only the value, try the below instead :

```
select map_values(map_filter(your_map_name, (k,v) -> k == 'desired_key)) from spark_table
```